# Scientific conference invitation Schengen visa (business or tourist)?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, spain

I am participating in a conference in Spain, I have an invitation letter from the university. Is my visa application for tourism or for Business ?

I appreciate if you can provide me with more advises since it is my firs Schengen visa application.

Comment: This type of thing is typically a business premise, unclear as to why you have doubts about it, do you plan to visit other countries or stay beyond the conference?

Comment: no, I want just to attend the conference and then return back.

Comment: In that case put down 'Business' and attach the requisite justifications.